# Creating an isometric CSS grid as my section background

Tags: css, background

I want to create a subtle Isometric CSS grid as a background for my hero section. Something similar to this: https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/isometric-grid-black-template-your-260nw-1546251851.jpg but without the vertical lines running through the grid. Would anyone know how I'd do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using background-image we can achive a background grid using css.

```css
body{
    background-color: #fff;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
150deg
, #ccc, #bbb 2px, transparent 1px, transparent 40px) , repeating-linear-gradient(
30deg
, #ccc, #BBB 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 40px);
    background-size: 81px 46px;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: you can add some shadows to give a 3D effect..  `body{
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: 
    linear-gradient(0deg,transparent 9%,#999 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 20%),
      linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 9%,#999 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 20%);
  background-size:50px 50px;
}`

Comment: this takes it halfway. I still need to make it isometric without affecting the content on the page

Comment: @btothemoon .. Updated the solution. check if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Updated my previous answer.

```css
body{
    background-color: #fff;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(150deg, #ccc, #bbb 0.5px, transparent 1px, transparent 40px) 
              , repeating-linear-gradient(30deg, #ccc, #BBB 0.5px, transparent 1px, transparent 40px)
              , repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc, #BBB 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 41px);
    background-size: 81px 46px;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```